# Recover deleted instances of recurrent events in Outlook

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I'm currently developing an app that synchronizes with Outlook Calendar.

I can perform the authentication flow, recover calendars and events but I'm having troubles with recurrent events. Outlook responses are something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "Recurrence": {
        "Pattern": {
          "Type": "Daily",
          "Interval": 1,
          "Month": 0,
          "DayOfMonth": 0,
          "FirstDayOfWeek": "Sunday",
          "Index": "First"
        },
        "Range": {
          "Type": "NoEnd",
          "StartDate": "2016-07-11",
          "EndDate": "0001-01-01",
          "RecurrenceTimeZone": "Romance Standard Time",
          "NumberOfOccurrences": 0
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

That's OK. That's not exactly the [RFC 5545 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) but it can be easily converted. The problem is that I'm not able to determine if some of the recurrent instances have been deleted.

RFC 5545 specifies that deleted dates should appear in the EXDATE field. Does Outlook have something similar? Is there any way to do it (besides recovering all instances)?

---

As a little example, what I want to achive is:

1. Create a daily event from Outlook site
2. Delete a couple of instances of that recurrent event from Outlook site (let's just say that I delete today and tomorrow's instances)
3. Recover the master event and somehow know that today and tomorrow's instances have been deleted

Answer (score 0):

At present, the Microsoft Graph doesn't support to get the single instance of recurrent appointment which was deleted.

As a workaround, we can get the patterns of recurrent appointment and all the occurrence during a period of time. Then we can calculate the appointments which already be deleted.

And if you require this feature, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com)

Comment: Wow, such a **basic** functionality and it's not implemented? The only workaround is to get events in  a time windows and cross dates to check if some have been deleted. Such a waste of resources! The more I use Outlook api the more I hate it